# hiding menu on click

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

I am using NullField() in one of my screen so that the default focus should not be on any of the button . but when i am clicking on the screen where no field is there , menu screen is being displayed. i dont want that menu screen to be poped up tough it should open when i click menu button.

Thanks alot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

override method.

```
protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time) {
            Field focus = UiApplication.getUiApplication().getActiveScreen()
                    .getLeafFieldWithFocus();
            if (focus instanceof NullField) {
                return true;
            }
            return super.navigationClick(status, time);
        }
```

Note:This code is only for giving you hint.